# Put a print button in window created from jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I am trying to add a print button inside the window thats created by js.
But its showing `[object Window]` instead of showing the link or button. What is an alternative solution?

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('a.print').click(function(){

var print_button = '<a href="javascript:window.print();" class="print">Print</a>';
var print_page = window.open('','Print','width=600,scrollbars=yes, height=700');
var html = print_page + '<h2><?php print t("Term & Condition"); ?></h2> <br/>' + 'somethings';
print_page.document.open();
print_page.document.write(html);
print_page.document.close();

return false;

}); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right,

```
function printDiv(divName) {
         // divName - is the div to be printed
         var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML; // get the div content
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML; //get a copy of original content
         document.body.innerHTML = printContents; //set the div content to body
         window.print(); // print 
         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents; // revert back to original content
}
```

Pass the div name that's is to be printed. There are a lot of jquery plugins which will allow you to help you out. Try googling.

If I'm mistaken your question correct me, I might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But I feel this line maybe wrong because it has `print_page` which is an object and I think it should be `print_button`. And `print_page` is a object and that's why you see `[object Window]`

`var html = print_page + '<h2><?php print t("Term & Condition"); ?></h2> <br/>' + 'somethings';`

Correct line is,

`var html = print_button + '<h2><?php print t("Term & Condition"); ?></h2> <br/>' + 'somethings';`

Comment: I agree having `print_page` instead of print_button is probably a mistake and should fix the problem